# Error: 'QGeoCoordinate' does not name a type

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry-10

I am C++ and BB10 begainer developer, I have a small problem while compiling that `'QGeoCoordinate' does not name a type` in both hpp and cpp
this is my hpp

```
#ifndef GLOBALOBJECTS_HPP_
#define GLOBALOBJECTS_HPP_
#include <QtLocationSubset/QGeoCoordinate>

namespace bb { namespace cascades { class Application; }}

extern QGeoCoordinate currentCoordinates;
extern double someVar;

#endif
```

and this is my cpp

```
#include "GlobalObjects.hpp"
#include <QtLocationSubset/QGeoCoordinate>

namespace bb { namespace cascades { class Application; }}
QGeoCoordinate currentCoordinates;
double  someVar;
```

**Notes** 
1- someVar works good but the problem in the currentCoordinates object
2- I added `lQtLocationSubset` lib on my .pro file

Comment: What is the problem, exactly?

Comment: Is `QGeoCoordinate` in a namespace?

Comment: While compiling I get "'QGeoCoordinate' does not name a type"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Eclipse to drill down into the include file QtLocationSubset/QGeoCoordinate you will find the macro QTMS_BEGIN_NAMESPACE which expands to:

```
namespace QtMobilitySubset {
```

So you need to refere to the class with a fully qualified name:

```
QtMobilitySubset::QGeoCoordinate
```

or specify the namespace:

```
using namespace QtMobilitySubset;
```